# Links reverting back to old file path in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a brochure set up in InDesign. The brochure was a copy of a previous version of this brochure, we are using different images and information but the same layout. The brochure has been given a different name. In the folder, I have a new links folder and have all of my new images inside. I have re-placed images with the new ones I'd like to use.

Twice now the links have reverted back to the old file path. Has anyone ever encountered this before or does anyone know why this could be happening?

We are working off of a server rather than locally so though perhaps that this could be the problem, however surely InDesign looks for the links folder, then the file name, and so knows what to display?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: *"We are working off of a server rather than locally"* Yup.. and it's reasons like this Adobe frowns upon that workflow. I *suspect* if the INDD file was *local* and merely the *links* were remote the issue may not occur.

Comment: Does the "revert" only affect the links? What if you were to change some text? Would your amended text revert as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be impossible for us to troubleshoot without knowledge of how your server is set up. Rather than figuring out how to change the server's behavior with InDesign, try an easy fix: rename your InDesign file AND rename the folder directories with the images being placed. This 20 second fix may spare you a long journey down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Edit all links into the new directory
2. Zip the old directory and change its place
3. Create a new package and replace all the picture in the new directory then edit again all links into your new directory

Answer (score 1):

When you package an InDesign document, the way I understand it, is that InDesign basically recreates the location path for all of the links to the computer version of "within a links folder that is located in the same folder as the InDesign file."

This way, when you send the InDesign file to someone, as long as they save the links folder in the same place as the InDesign file, the links do not need to be updated.

However, it could be that something about your particular workflow has "broken" this connection. In your place, I would probably be tempted to lose a day or two into trying to figure out why it happened--but let's be honest, you probably just want to solve the problem and move forward with your work.

I think the easiest way to solve this problem would be to make sure that all of the links in your InDesign file are correctly linked. If any of these links are located in a file called "Links," then you need to rename that folder, and go back into your InDesign file and update the link location (which should be fairly easy as InDesign by default looks for additional missing links in the folder once you relink one file).

Once your links are all correctly linked, then use the "Package" option to have InDesign create a new folder called "Links" and place a copy of all of the linked files into that new folder.

Once you have packaged the InDesign document, you can save it, and all of your links should then be directed to the new Links folder that was just created.

If you still have trouble, it is time to try [resetting your preferences](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/setting-preferences.html) in InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

You have to repackage the file and tick both `Copy Linked Graphics` and `Update Graphic Links In Package`

If you copy an existing package from/to a server the graphic links are not updated.

[image: Screenshot of Create Package Folder UI]